# Is there a way to know if a cleartext substring is present in a hash?

Tags: hash

Let's say I have 4 strings - A, B, C & D. I concatenate and hash them in any order: A + B + C + D or A + C + B + D and send it to another party. Let's call this X.

I can also send a hash of A separately to the same party (but cannot send it in plain text). Is there any algorithm that I can use to figure out whether the string A is used while creating X?

Comment: What is the actual goal here? Because if the other party doesn't know $A$, then it's quite pointless if $A$ is a substring of $X$ or not.

Comment: How about a [Merkle tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree)?

Comment: If the max entropy of the other pieces (B+C+D) is under maybe 40-80 bits depending on how rich and powerful you are, brute force works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: not really.  I think the closest thing you're going to find is a "cryptographic accumulator." I can accumulate the separate hashes of the strings A,B,C,D.  But even then, testing whether A is in the result requires more than just the accumulator itself - you also needs a piece of data called a "witness for A" - which is a separate number that "proves" that A is in the accumulator.

Merkle trees have the same problem - to prove that A is in the tree, you need more than just the final total of the tree.  You also need to know where A appeared in the tree, and the hashes of the other branches of the tree.